# Tkinker Replace the bottom taskbar icon with something else

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am wanting to replace the icon at the bottom of the screen.
Example: [image]
I am aware of how to remove the icon in the toolbar this is at the bottom of the screen.

```
import ctypes 


def Mbox(title, text, style):
    root = root.iconbitmap(default='app.ico')

    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)

    root = Mbox('Your title', 'Your text', 1)
```

I keep getting –

```
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please upload the image on this site, so the link doesn't become invalid in the years to come, leaving behind a corpse

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error message - you'e setting `root = root.iconbitmap(...)`. What is `root` before this line?

Comment: On which line are you getting this error? Please fix your indentation in the code example. Also show us, how you create root at first place.

Answer (score 0):

import tkinter and set your root variable to `Tk()`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
```